# Show that $A$ cartesian closed category it does not imply $A^{J}$ cartesian closed category

Tags: category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Hello I have been looking for one example of this problem

If $A$ cartesian closed category then it does not imply $A^{J}$ is a cartesian closed category with $J$ any category.

I do not have any idea or hint about this .
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102372/show-that-a-cartesian-closed-need-not-imply-aj-is-cartesian-closed

Comment: I have read that example however, I do not ge it in some parts. That's why I wrote this question. Any help would be great for me.

Comment: Which parts didn't you understand? In his comment he is using essentially Yoneda Lemma to obtain $F(0)\cong \text{Nat}(\hom(0, -), F)\cong \text{Nat}(1,F)$.

Comment: I see, that is why  $G^{F}(0)\cong Nat(G,F)$, however i do not see why that is a problem?

Comment: Let us write $F$ for the functor described in the answer. The problem is that if $F^F$ exists its codomain should to be the category of finite sets, however $F^F(0) \cong \text{Nat}(F,F)$ is infinite.

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry for the problems.